# publisher confirms the message

Tags: spring-rabbit

As per my understanding, the order in which broker confirms the messages is not guaranteed.

Considering my above understanding,lets assume if publisher confirms, i get a message confirm for corelation id 4. Now my question is, can i assume all the previous corelation id's(1,2,3) are also confirmed?

Can you please any one give the answer for the same. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your understanding is correct, but the `ConfirmListener` callback methods have a boolean parameter `multiple`. If the argument is `true` then this confirm means all previous tags are confirmed; if false, then not.

If you use the `RabbitTemplate`, with confirms enabled, the template will issue a separate confirm for each individual publish, together with its correlation data, regardless of whether the confirm from RabbitMQ is `multiple`.

Comment: Thanks for the same! I tried this by using the java code and its worked. But how i can achieve same behavior means multiple publisher confirm through spring rabbitmq..i am stuck here..can you please give the answer for this?

Comment: Thank you..As per my understanding from your post is publisher always get confirmation per individual publish message..regardless of whether the confirm from RabbitMQ is multiple.

Comment: And Can you give the answer about the order of published message and order of confirmed message by broker..is it in same order or order might be changed for confirmed message by broker?

Comment: The RabbitMQ confirms API is very basic. Spring AMQP keeps track of pending confirms with correlation data so you can figure out which publish the confirmation is for. If we receive a `multiple` confirm, the callback will be called for each pending confirm, in order, with its correlation data.